# What is technical difference between free and paid SSL certificate handshakes?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

If the SSL is all about encryption and public-private key, why we have multiple type of certificates(like regular and wildcard)?

Is there any third-party server in process of paid-certificates handshake?

Comment: There is no difference between the handshakes, and no third-party server involved in either case. There is no practical difference between the certificates either, except the expiry periods. We have wildcard certificates so that servers can speak for multiple subdomains within a domain controlled by their owner. Off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The origin of the certificate does not matter for the TLS handshake itself. For the verification of the certificate it is only relevant if the issuing certificate agency is included in the applications or systems trust store. There are CA like Let's Encrypt which issue certificates for free and which are included in most systems trust store.

For the various types of certificates (wildcard etc) same can be said, i.e. it does not matter if this certificate was issued by a paid CA or not.

EV certificates are a bit different. These were historically considered special since the validation of the certificate owner was more tough and not everybody could get one. They were also more expensive due to this process. And only some CA would be able to issue such certificate and these CA where marked as such in the browsers But the relevance of these EV certificates is going down and some browsers already don't show them as special anymore.